# PHP Http Pooling Vs Curl Multi

Tags: php, curl, httprequest, curl-multi

I want to make a parallel requests from server A to server B using PHP. Which is the best way among Curl Multi Handle and Http Pooling.

What are the pros and cons of these two.

Please suggest me an optimized way which is best in performance, memory consumption, CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

PHP really eats away at memory, as oppopsed to a standard CURL command. Also curl cannot handle parallel requests. The multi command issues requests in blocks that will hang until all are completed. You cannot make parallel requests in PHP as far as I am aware. The best solution is to use xargs and curl from the command line:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -L 1 -P 10 timeout 45 curl
```

This will download urls (or curl commands) from a file. -L means the number of lines and -P means the number of parallel connections you want.

Running this via exec or system in PHP is the most efficient. ALternatively you will want to use a CURL wrapper like:

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

But as mentioned, it is not parallel.